# Add view to constraintLayout with constraints similar to another child

Tags: android, view, imageview, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have a **constraint layout** (alpha9) with views spread all over it, and I have one particular ImageView that I need to replicate and add more of like it.
The layout is like so :
[image: Basic layout]

The main purpose is to animate 5 of those "coin" imageViews when the button is pressed. The imageViews i need to generated sha'll have exact properties of the the imageView behind the Button down below (with same constraints)
[image: The imageView behind the button]

What i tried to do is the following :

```
private ImageView generateCoin() {
    ImageView coin = new ImageView(this);
    constraintLayout.addView(coin,-1,originCoinImage.getLayoutParams());//originCoinImage is the imageView behind the button
    coin.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_coin);
    coin.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    coin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return coin;
}
```

And it failed. **EDIT:** It failed to show what i wanted , sometimes it shows a coin in the top left of the screen , sometimes it doesn't show anything but either way , the number of coins increments (meaning the animation is trying to actually do something and then calling the onAnimationFinished method)

I used for animation the library EasyAndroidAnimations

the code is as follows :

**MainActivity.java**

```
@OnClick(R.id.addCoin)
public void addCoin() {
//        for (int x = 0 ; x < 5 ; x++){
    final View newCoin = generateCoin();

    sendCoin(newCoin, 300, new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(com.easyandroidanimations.library.Animation animation) {
            incrementCoins();
            constraintLayout.removeView(newCoin);
            shakeCoin(targetCoinImage, 200, null);
        }
    });
//        }
}

private void incrementCoins() {
    coins++;
    coinNumber.setText(String.valueOf(coins));
}

private void sendCoin(View coinView, long duration, AnimationListener listener) {
    new TransferAnimation(coinView)
            .setDestinationView(targetCoinImage)
            .setDuration(duration)
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
            .setListener(listener)
            .animate();
}

private void shakeCoin(View coinView, long duration, AnimationListener listener) {
    new ShakeAnimation(coinView)
            .setDuration(duration)
            .setShakeDistance(6f)
            .setNumOfShakes(5)
            .setListener(listener)
            .animate();
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="seaskyways.canvasanddrawtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Coins : "
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coinNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coinOrigin"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addCoin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/addCoin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addCoin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coin"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/addCoin" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coinTarget"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/coinNumber"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/coinNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/coinNumber"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addCoin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do u get as output when you press the button?/

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the coin to go from the bottom button to the top coin and when the animation finishes, the number of coins increment by one. So you want to increment them by five, which means 5 of the coins should be animated from the bottom to the top coin. Am I close?

Comment: Exactly what i want , however shall i do it with one coin , then a million won't make a difference @mihanovak1024

Comment: So the animation should just go vertically up? Or does it have to move or anything? What animation did you have in mind? Will a simple TranslateAnimation do?

Comment: @mihanovak1024 it isn't about the animation , it is about the imageview being placed right programmatically

Comment: @Seaskyways then I would recommend, that you position the imageview on the place you want it to be at the end of animation and set it's visibility to either gone or invisible, then animate it from the bottom of the screen to the actual view location and on the start of animation, set it's visibility to visible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` cache its parameters, and is associated to the widget you use it on, so you cannot simply pass one widget's layoutParams to another.

You have to instead generate a new layoutParams for your new object, and copy the corresponding fields.

For example, if you have something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then you could do:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();

Button anotherButton = new Button(this);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

newParams.leftToLeft = params.leftToLeft;
newParams.topToTop = params.topToTop;
newParams.leftMargin = params.leftMargin;
newParams.topMargin = params.topMargin;

layout.addView(anotherButton, -1, newParams);
```

This would put the second button exactly in the same place as the one defined in XML.

Comment: Hi Nicolas Roard, 
If I have a complex ui, for example, the Button is dynamic and has many layout params and many constraints, what i want to do is adding a new Button on the same position, how should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, thank you.
I implement it by the following way:

val screenshotViewLayoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(cl.width,
                    cl.height)
            screenshotView.layoutParams = screenshotViewLayoutParams
            cs.connect(screenshotView.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, cl.x.toInt())
            cs.connect(screenshotView.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, cl.y.toInt())