# What is the equivalent of layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to add some constraints to a `TextView` within a `ConstraintLayout` programmatically. I know that I  had to use `ConstraintSet`, but I have no idea how to add the xml attribute: `layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf` (and its equivalencies) on that `textView` in Java in android.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : How to programatically set layout\_constraintRight\_toRightOf "parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670618/android-how-to-programatically-set-layout-constraintright-torightof-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set like this,

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(layout); // root layout

// If you want to align parent to the layout left
constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);

// If you want to align to the left of one more textview - second text view
constraintSet.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, textView1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);

/*______________________________
|      Text1     Text2       |
|                            |*/
constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
```