# How to debug ConstraintSet bug when there is no error shown but result is unexpected

Tags: android

I am learning android and doing a simple calculator. I am building the calculator inputs button programmatically by iterating a list of operator labels like such

`final String[] inputLabels = {"9", "8", "7", "/", "6" ...}`

It will be 4 rows and 4 columns like this

```
// please do not mind me about the design
9 8 7 /
6 5 4 x
1 2 3 -
0 AC = +
```

Those inputs will be under `ConstraintLayout`, because I want to learn using it. But before going into my logic of how constrainting those inputs from my 1D array, I want to test if simple code such as creating 2 buttons and constraint them works, which it does not and that is the main problem I want to solve here.

I already tried googling it and they all seems very simple, it is strange that I could not achieve such simple thing and I tried to google my problem but I found nothing(sorry If those problem exists and I didnt found it)

These below are what I tried to follows:

- [Android : How to programmatically set layout_constraintRight_toRightOf "parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670618/android-how-to-programmatically-set-layout-constraintright-torightof-parent)
- [ConstraintLayout: change constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically/45265164)

Here is the `main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="calculatedValue"
            type="java.lang.String"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/calculate_value_display"
            bind:calculatedValue="@{calculatedValue}" />

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.calculator.CalculatorInputs"
            android:id="@+id/calculatorInputs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The `calculator_inputs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".CalculatorInputs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/calculatorInputs"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The `MainActivity.java` is just what it is when the project created and here is the `CalculatorInputs.java`

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class CalculatorInputs extends Fragment {
  private final String[] inputLabels = {"7", "8", "9", "/", "4", "5", "6", "x", "1", "2", "3", "-", "0", "AC", "=", "+"};

  private final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams buttonConstraintLayout =
      new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(220, 150);

  private final float buttonTextSize = 20.f;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_inputs, container, false);

    return rootView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.calulatorInputs);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    final ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>(this.inputLabels.length);

    while (buttons.size() < this.inputLabels.length) {
      buttons.add(null);
    }

    int buttonIndex = 0;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////// BEGIN HERE ////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    final ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(layout);

    final Button button1 = this.createButton("X");
    final Button button2 = this.createButton("Y");

    layout.addView(button1);

    constraintSet.connect(
      button1.getId(),
      ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
      ConstraintSet.RIGHT
    );

    constraintSet.connect(
      button1.getId(),
      ConstraintSet.TOP,
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
      ConstraintSet.TOP
    );

    constraintSet.applyTo(layout);

    layout.addView(button2);

    constraintSet.connect(
      button2.getId(),
      ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
      ConstraintSet.RIGHT
    );

    constraintSet.connect(
      button2.getId(),
      ConstraintSet.TOP,
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
      ConstraintSet.TOP
    );

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////// END HERE /////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  }

  Button createButton(final String buttonLabel) {
    final Button button = new Button(this.getActivity());

    button.setLayoutParams(this.buttonConstraintLayout);
    button.setText(buttonLabel);
    button.setTextSize(this.buttonTextSize);
    button.setId(View.generateViewId());

    return button;
  }
}
```

So below are the expected output and the reality:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should execute `constraintSet.clone(layout)` after `layout.addView(button1)`.
BTW,you can use Layout Inspector to check your layout running on the device,it shows a View Tree and you can find where is your buttons gone.

Update:Change your `button.setLayoutParams(this.buttonConstraintLayout);` to `button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(220, 150));` in `createButton`,do not share the View's LayoutParams object.

Comment: Thanks @JiajiaGu. You helped me learned another step to debug the UI in android. So I inspect the layout using the layout inspector, i found out that both of my button have 0 width and height and also their position are the same, which means they are still overlapping. Strange when I do not set constraint on them, they have expected width and height, just they are overlapping each other since it is being put inside `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that I shared the `LayoutParams` for every button creation, that is why it didnt work.

Inside the `createButton` method, it works if I changed to this

```
  Button createButton(final String buttonLabel) {
    final Button button = new Button(this.getActivity());

    button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(220, 150);
    button.setText(buttonLabel);
    button.setTextSize(this.buttonTextSize);
    button.setId(View.generateViewId());

    return button;
  }
```