# Is it possible to change "layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf" programatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android

There is a HomeFragment and in the "onCreateView", I want to change the "layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf" of a view, Is it possible?

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoViewMain"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/appCompatToggleButton"
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewMain" />
```

Change

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewMain"
```

to:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoViewMain"
```

Tried code but doesn't work:

```
ConstraintLayout  constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);
AppCompatToggleButton appCompatToggleButton= root.findViewById(R.id.appCompatToggleButton);
constraintLayout.addView(appCompatToggleButton);
ConstraintSet   constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.connect(appCompatToggleButton.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 
constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670618/android-how-to-programmatically-set-layout-constraintright-torightof-parent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : How to programmatically set layout\_constraintRight\_toRightOf "parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670618/android-how-to-programmatically-set-layout-constraintright-torightof-parent)