# How to programmatically set layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf “parent” of a RelativeLayout? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I would like to change the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` of an element at runtime. I tried to solve it using this question/answers:

[Android : How to programmatically set layout_constraintRight_toRightOf "parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670618/android-how-to-programmatically-set-layout-constraintright-torightof-parent)

Unfortunately my element is a `RelativeLayout`, so it can not be cast to `ConstraintLayout`, like in [this answer with constraintSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41672545)

Then I tried to solve it based on [this answer with LayoutParams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61424113/3042117), but `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` has no property like `toBottomOf`.

The layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myElement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otherElement">
    
    <!-- Child elements -->
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @PiyushMaheswari I just tried to use the ones in the linked answers. The first one failed at `ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.myElement)` and in the second case I am not able to find the needed attribute.

Comment: Please provide us with the XML code of your layout

Comment: @GrigoriiRaudiiainen I updated the question with the XML

Comment: That's not enough to find the root cause of an issue. If you're trying to change the constraint of the RelativeLayout with id `myElement` we need make sure that the parent of that layout is indeed `ConstraintLayout`, otherwise that's meaningless. If you're trying to change constraints of the child of RelativeLayout, then that's impossible because this attributes have no affect inside of RelativeLayout


Constraint of what view are you trying to change and what is the parent of that view in layout?

Comment: @GrigoriiRaudiiainen The parent of that `myElement ` is the root element `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`. The referenced `otherElement` is an `ImageButton`

Answer (score 3):

In order to change `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` attribute of your `RelativeLayout` in the runtime, you can do one of the following:

1. Clone ConstraintSet of the ConstraintLayout, that is the parent view of your RelativeLayout. Update the constraint in the cloned ConstraintSet and then apply the ConstraintSet back to the ConstraintLayout.

Sample code:

```
//ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.myElement).getParent()
constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout); 
constraintSet.connect(R.id.myElement, ConstraintSet.TOP, [other element Id], ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Please Note: You should pass ConstraintLayout to the ConstraintSet.clone() method, not the RelativeLayout.

2. Modify LayoutParams of `myElement` view!

Like that:

```
//RelativeLayout myElement = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.myElement)
LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) myElement.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.topToBottom = [id of the another view];
myElement.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

In that case, if the parent of `myElement` is `ConstraintLayout` you'll get ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams class in `myElement.getLayoutParams();` that have property `topToBottom`.

Comment: I tried the second one, but I get this error: `android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: @IterAtor The RelativeLayout itself should have ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams. Are you sure you're trying to get params out of the correct view? Can you please show us some code, how do you do that?

Comment: Perfectly working.